# Compile error in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed VBA code to search the particular email type (for example .@gmail.com) in Excel. It will mark the next cell as a "TRUE" which is matched by condition.

I got compile error in do while loop

[image: compile time error loop without do]

```
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("@email.com","@gmail.com")

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
for each emailarray in myarray
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("emailarray", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then 
           'c.EntireRow.Delete
             row_num = Split(c.Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False, RowAbsolute:=False), "A")
             Range("C" & row_num(1)).Value = "True"
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

next emailarray
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing and `End If`

but also you have  `Do ... Loop While`

when it looks like it should be for your circumstances

```
Do While
....
Loop
```

or

```
Do Until
...
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a `end if` to your code.

```
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    'c.EntireRow.Delete
    row_num = Split(c.Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False, RowAbsolute:=False), "A") 
    Range("C" & row_num(1)).Value = "True" 
End If
```